# InvalidStateError when opening IndexedDB in Firefox 21

Tags: javascript, firefox, indexeddb

I am using Firefox 21 built for Linux Mint. When trying to open an IndexedDB database from within a script tag I get an InvalidStateError. However, I do not get an error when trying to open a database from the JavaScript console.

The following code gives an error

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                indexedDB.open("MyNewDatabase");
            });
         </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

while entering `indexedDB.open("MyNewDatabase");` in the console properly returns an `IDBOpenDBRequest` object. Any ideas what might cause this strange behaviour?

I am aware of [Invalid state Error in Firefox for Indexed Db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14082932/invalid-state-error-in-firefox-for-indexed-db) and [InvalidStateError while opening IndexedDB in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13972385/invalidstateerror-while-openning-indexeddb-in-firefox), but both questions/answers could not help me figure out the problem.

Comment: What happens if you put the the `indexedDB.open` call behind a timeout of - say - one second? Maybe when the `ready` callback is triggered the dbms is not ready yet?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I have tried calling `indexedDB.open` with a timeout of 5 seconds (so that I can call it from the console before it gets executed in the script tag). Unfortunately, I still get the same behaviour.

Comment: Is that all the code that is actually there - no transaction going on?

Comment: Yes, that is all. No transactions, nothing else. You could also leave out the jQuery loading, as the document ready function has no impact on this problem (I just wanted to avoid a comment like "try wrapping indexeddb.open in a document ready function"...).

Comment: Can you provide some more information? bind the on error handler to the dbrequest var x = indexeddb.open("..."); x.onerror = function (e){ .... }; then put a breakpoint inside the error handler and let me know what the e.target.errorcode is. This should give some more info about what is the real error.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I have tried what you suggested: Unfortunately there is no field `e.target.errorcode` (undefined), and e.target.error gives me `DOMError { constructor=DOMError, name="InvalidStateError"}`. This object also does not contain any error code.

Comment: I just tested on Firefox 21.0 on Mac OS 10.8.4 and it works fine. Maybe there's something wrong with your build of Firefox, is it from apt-get?

Comment: Yes, it is the official version from the repository installed via apt-get.

Answer (score 2):

This reply is probably too late to be useful, but have you checked the dom.indexedDB.enabled pref is true in about:config?

I ended up reading the Gecko indexedDB source code to discover that I had flipped that pref to false in the past for reasons unknown!

Comment: Thanks, this was the problem for me as well. Almost the equivalent of "Is the computer plugged in?"

Answer (score 0):

Have you tred passing in version as the second parameter to indexedDB.open? I recall some random conversation I found on the web where there was a decision to make it non optional and such. I believe spec says it defaults to 1 if not provided but you might want to at least see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I have tried calling `indexedDB.open` with several different version numbers. They all exhibit the same behaviour.

Comment: Hmm. You do know you do not have to wait until the DOM is ready to interact with the DB. The DB is independently ready of the DOM. You might be getting an error that you are not logging. Add an error listener to the open request. Also, triple check you do not have the DB already open in another tab as there is some funky code dealing with simultaneous access behind the scenes that sometimes leads to a DOM 11 exception if something is not configured properly.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! I am sure that the database is not open in any other tab as I closed everything else before opening this document. I have attached an error handler to the open request via `indexedDB.open("MyNewDatabase").onerror = function(event) { console.log(event); };` but it did not log anything else but the invalid state error. Did you think about another way to add an error listener?

Comment: add a listener for onblocked as well. you closed the tabs, so "it should never happen", but quite often things that should never happen do happen. if you can rule out on blocked, on error, then use something like chrome's browser tool to print the stack trace of the error. there should be some properties saying why it is in an invalid state. things like a store not existing, transactional issues, bad lookups, etc.

Comment: The `onblocked` handler does not get called so I assume that the event is not fired. Unfortunately I cannot use the chrome browser tools as this is a firefox specific problem (chrome works well).

Comment: Try testing without jquery to rule out any jquery interference. I believe they left it to plugins but something might be moving into the core. Avoid using the provider specific globals (e.g. mozIndexedDB). Are you in an extension context or a basic page, and are you loading the page remotely or using file://? Are you doing other things like messing with temp storage quota? Is this the first time you are trying to get db up and running or has it run before. Explore the property results of console.dir(indexedDB.open('test')) and list all the relevant ones, look for error related props.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome and Firefox...you must include the version number. In IE10...you must NOT. IE10 further uses the prefix 'msIndexedDB' and the use of transaction enumerations is likewise inconsistent with Microsoft. Some versions of IE use MS prefixed enum values, others use a string. Grrr.